# SASS Imports misbehaving

Tags: html, css, import, sass, importerror

I have just started learning SCSS and what I have noticed is, there is something going on with importing partials in the 'main.scss' file. I am using live-server to host the website locally and every time I modify something, in simple words, it doesn't work.
It doesn't show up on the website when it refreshes automatically in the browser.
And now, what I see is all my styles are gone, even though everything in my files is still the same.

1. This is my main.scss file below.

```
    // ABSTRACTS
    @use "abstracts/functions";
    @use "abstracts/mixins";
    @use "abstracts/variables";

    //PAGES 
    @use "pages/home";

    //COMPONENTS
    @use "components/button";

    //BASE
    @use "base/base";
    @use "base/animations";
    @use "base/utilities";
    @use "base/typography";

    //LAYOUTS
    @use "layouts/header";
    @use "layouts/grid";
```

**Note:I also used @import for this, but it's the same.**

2. This is my partial which I am trying to modify.

```
    .row {
        max-width: $grid-width;
        background-color:yellow;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: $gutter-vertical;
    }
```

What happens is, the background color doesn't change. It just stays the same. It's not a code problem since I have tried the same with the CSS code inside a style tag. So I am sure it is related to SASS import.

Comment: Have you disabled browser caching?

Comment: No..I haven't tried that.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a number of problems:

1. The element you're trying to style doesn't have `class="row"` set on it.
2. You're not importing the right partial. It's impossible to tell what each of the files you're importing are.
3. Something is overriding the style that you're setting. For example, a more specific selector (e.g., `div.row`) or something using `!important`.

The best way to test is to use your developer tools to look at the imported stylesheet (be sure it's there, of course) and search to see if you can find the rule that you've defined. Then, look at the element you're attempting to style and be sure it has the `row` classname. Last, check to make sure that nothing else is applying a style which would override the style that you expect to find.

Comment: What I noticed now is that the output file i.e. style.css where the compiled SASS code is supposed to be, has all the contents of the main.scss file i.e. the import statements but I don't know why that is happening. 
And even after I fix that, I still have the problem of changes not showing up on the website.

Comment: okay, I fixed the first problem. I used @import in place of @ use again and styles are back, which means there's some major difference between @ import and @ use that I do not understand right now (like the noob I am).
However, my style and file modifications in partials still don't get updated on the website.

Comment: I did what you asked and used the Chrome Developer Tools to check the **CSS** Stylesheet. What I noticed is that even though, suppose, I change a colour in my partial and then link it to my main.scss file, the change isn't reflected in the style.css file. This is the problem I've been facing.